# How do I reference a cell reference from another cell (which leads to another worksheet cell reference)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sheet 1 Cell A1 contains value '6'.

Sheet 2 Cell A6 contains value 'apple'.

I am in Sheet1. How do I link to apple.
I want to make Sheet 1 Cell A1 a variable so I can change it.

I tried Sheet2!A & "A1" but it does not work. Please help.

Checked on google but they only have variable cell references that refer to own worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!A:A, Sheet1!A1)
```

**Note:** The way you tried is possible through the ***volatile*** `INDIRECT()` function, e.g: `=INDIRECT("Sheet2!A"&Sheet1!A1)`, but this is not recommended since it would re-calculate on a ton of [events](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm). At least, the use of `INDEX()` is semi-volatile.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the cell reference starts with an equals sign. Type this into the cell in sheet 1: `=Sheet2!A1`.

Same with formulas, they have to start with equals signs.